# how to remove pin from map after deleting pin at detail screen pop over to map view pin is still on map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkannotation

i am doing map application .where i am showing annotation pin on map .On pin there is accessory button on click of pin accessory button it navigate to pin detail page.In detail page there is a delete button to delete place .after deleting while i am pop to map view the pin is showing on map .but my object array decremented by 1.But pins are  showing as previous how to solve it .My  requirement is ti aftre deleting when user  pop to map view that pin will not show on map view.Please help me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try this method just call this method when you remove annotation..

```
-(void) reloadMap
{
    [yourMapView setRegion:yourMapView.region animated:TRUE];
}
```

**Option**

Else just remove all annotation and add again with your array object.. remove annotation like this

```
 MKCoordinateRegion region;
 MKCoordinateSpan span;
 span.latitudeDelta=0.04;
 span.longitudeDelta=0.04;

region.span=span;  
region.center = currentLocation; 
[MymapView removeAnnotations:[MymapView annotations]];
MyAnnotation *ann = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init]; ///This is My Annotation class which i create for display detail of location
ann.title =MymapView.userLocation.title;  
ann.subtitle = MymapView.userLocation.subtitle;
ann.coordinate = currentLocation;
ann.annLocation=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f%f",currentLocation.longitude,currentLocation.latitude];
[MymapView addAnnotation:ann];

[MymapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[MymapView regionThatFits:region];
```

Comment: @RanjanSahu see updated code .. just follow the flow of code and chnage something with ur requirement its very easy and working dude....

Comment: @RanjanSahu try this method.. -(void) reloadMap
{
    [yourMapView setRegion:yourMapView.region animated:TRUE];
}